# this.state.projects.map is not a function - React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I try to return my data from api which I get by Axios. But console return error:

this.state.projects.map is not a function

What could be the reason ?

```
export default class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projects: []
        };
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('/api/projects').then(response => {
            this.setState({
                projects: response.data
            });
        }).catch(errors => {
            console.log(errors)
        })

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state);

        return(
            <div className="container">
                <li>{this.state.projects.map(project => <div>{project.name}</div>)}</li>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to check if `response.data` is an typeof array?

Comment: @tmhao2005 that has to be the problem

Comment: @TilakMaddy Yeah :)

Comment: @tmhao2005. lol, of course. Should be response.data.data. Works great. Thank you !